# Why would/should this even be allowed?

Tags: java, syntax

I know not all WTFs are created equal but why would this even be valid. It does compile and only complains when you run it because it doesn't have `static void main` method, but other than that, it's syntactically correct.
I tried giving it the `main` method, put it in a file named `_.java` and it did run.

```
class _<_>
{
    <_> _ _(_ _){ return (_)_; }
}
```

So obviously the "thing" inside `class` is a method which takes an argument whose name is the same as its type and returns whatever it got as argument. The `(_)_` is obviously some casting.
But I don't get the part before the `(_ _)`.
I guess the method's name is `_`, but what is `<_> _`? If it's generics, then shouldn't it be `_<_>`?

Comment: Replace `_` with something like `A` and see if then makes sense...

Comment: Yeah. I've tried that, still don't get the `<_>` at the beginning of the method.

Comment: I think you'd answer yourself if you answer: "Why not?"

Answer (score 2):

Replace _ with something use full as suggested. Then you may see that `<_> _ _(_ _)` part is `<T> Node foo(Node node)`. So it is the method name and the return type really.

```
class Node<T> {

    <T> Node foo(Node node) {
        return (Node) node;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node<String> a = new Node();
        Node<String> b = new Node();
        a.foo(b);
    }
}
```

Comment: hmmm... so I guess I just never wrote generics that way. I'd normally put `Node<T>`. Well, it is what it is.

Answer (score 1):

The approach taken by @ravindrab is the right one, but the result is not correct.

1. The declaration of the method type parameter `<T>` (`<_>`) in the original source code) *shadows* the declaration of the class type `Node` (`_`); so the argument is of type `T`, not of type `Node`
2. The method type parameter also shadows the class's type parameter, so to avoid confusion it's better to give it a different name, like `X`.

Result:

```
class Node<X> {
    <T> T foo(T t) {
        return (T) t;
    }
}
```

The rules for shadowing are explained in [JLS section 6.4.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.1). The specific one that applies to this case is:

> A declaration `d` of a type named `n` shadows the declarations of any
>   other types named `n` that are in scope at the point where `d` occurs
>   throughout the scope of `d`.

Comment: An easier way to verify this is in Eclipse: go to the `_` within the cast `(_)`, and select "Open Declaration" (F3). The cursor will jump to the definition of the type parameter; the `<_>` so that cast is to that type parameter's type.